# DelegationToAClassWhichIsNotLoaded error with Moose and XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, moose

i have a simple test class using Moose, with a XML::LibXML::Document attribute, but get an error when I use this test class.
The test class is:

```
package moosetest;

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

use Moose;

has dom => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'XML::LibXML::Document', required => 0, handles => qr/^( findnodes | documentElement | setDocumentElement | toString | toFile )$/x );


1;
```

Then it's used in test.pl:

```
use XML::LibXML;

use moosetest;

my $tt = moosetest->new();
```

And when I run test.pl, I get an error:

The dom attribute is trying to delegate to a class which has not been loaded - XML::LibXML::Document

I'm using perlbrew, XML::LibXML is installed (I can instantiate a XML::LibXML::Document object without using Moose), Moose has been successfully installed, too.

Looks like I'm missing something important here, but i can't find the source of my problem...

Thanks for any help.

Francois.

Answer (score 1):

`Moose::Meta::Attribute::_find_delegate_metaclass` uses `Moose::Util::_is_package_loaded` which looks for `XML::LibXML::Document` in @INC.  However, the package `XML::LibXML::Document` is inside of XML/LibXML.pm.

Using an array instead regex for handles avoids this problem:

```
handles => [ qw( findnodes documentElement setDocumentElement toString toFile ) ],
```

Comment: OK, it works with the change you suggested. Still strange to me...
I will fix the code, but it used to work with a previous version of perl (5.16), XML::LibXML and Moose, the error appeared when I tried to upgrade my development environment...

Comment: OK, answering to myself: it used to work with Moose 2.0802 and fails with the latest version. May be due to the change in 2.1100 (changed the class loader)...